# Visual Foxpro or VFP Version 9: Networking from NAS

Tags: visual-foxpro

In VFP9 I need to move the database to a Netgear ReadyNas Duo V2 shared network drive.
I don't know exactly which files to move or where and how to put the network path.

I've been trying for 2 days and keep getting error 2005 (...."table file users.dbf has moved"....) at start-up and now time is running out.

Comment: FYI: Foxpro files over a network share are tremendously slow, and they also don't support concurrency well.  You might be better off moving to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Although DaveB provided all the extensions, but I think you might be looking for something a little more specific to the data and tables.

In VFP, if you have a database container, you can do it a few ways... have a database located in one folder/path, and the actual TABLES in another path... Not anything I would recommend, but that MAY be what you are encountering.  The database will have the path where the tables are EXPECTED to be found when you try to open them.

The other is to have both the database AND the tables in the same folder.  There are 3 files for the database itself

```
.dbc -- database
.dcx -- compound index of database 
.dct -- memo field content for database

Additionally, the tables can have up to 3 files each with respective suffixes

.dbf -- single table
.cdx -- compound index for the single table
.fpt -- memo field content for the single table
```

So, if you have moved the tables from one location to another and they don't have same paths in expected location, that will cause you some headaches.  If you have VFP, you can open the database as a table and browse it to see what is expected where.  For example

```
CD Whatever\Your\DataPathIs
use NameOfYourDatabase.dbc   (yes, explicitly add the .dbc suffix)
browse for objectType = "Table"
```

then, if you double-click the "memo" field column for the property, you'll see a bunch of non-viewable characters represented by square boxes and then a path that corresponds to where the database is EXPECTING to find the file.

This might be the missing piece you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help guys. I am having trouble trying to reply, can I have this re-opened please? I moved all 6 file types to the Nas (\\Nas-a0-3d-36\Daimler) and followed DRapp's instructions ok til I got to the last bit, I couldn't find the "memo" field. a table opened up with Objectid, Parentid, Objecttpye & Objectname but no "memo" field column. Could you please tell me the commands to set the Nas path to the tables into the program permanently. Thanks again, Optorock

Comment: had another go, scrolled way across and I think I found it:after 15 little boxes it says "members.dbf" with no path then a few more boxes and "mbnumber" and one more box.

Comment: Recompiled and now getting "Locate Database" error 'instantiating cursor object...' at start-up

Comment: @Optorock, the "memo" is not a colum name, but the "SHOW" a value of "memo" (if no content in the cell) or "Memo" (upper case IF there IS something in the cell).  Double-click that and it will open up a secondary window showing the CONTENT of the field.  The COLUMN you want is the column called "PROPERTY"

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there are no hardcoded file paths anywhere. You might need to recreate the file tree from a specific root. The following looks like a good list of files to look for.

From [Visual FoxPro File Extensions and File Types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130686):

```
File Extensions and File Types used by Visual FoxPro

Extension   File type
----------------------------------------------
.act        Documenting Wizard action diagram
.app        Generated application
.cdx        Compound index
.dbc        Database
.dbf        Table
.dct        Database memo
.dcx        Database index
.dll        Windows Dynamic Link Library
.err        Compilation error
.exe        Executable program
.fky        Macro
.fll        FoxPro Dynamic Link Library
.fmt        Format File
.fpt        Table memo
.frt        Report memo
.frx        Report
.fxp        Compiled program
.hlp        Graphical Help
.idx        Index, compact index
.krt        Used in the recreation of a .dbc file
            NOTE: The .KRT extension is not listed in the online Help.
.lbt        Label memo
.lbx        Label
.lst        Documenting Wizard list
.mem        Memory variable saveDoslives
.mnt        Menu memo
.mnx        Menu
.mpr        Generated menu program
.mpx        Compiled menu program
.ocx        OLE control
.pjt        Project memo
.pjx        Project
.prg        Program
.qpr        Generated query program
.qpx        Compiled query program
.sct        Form memo
.scx        Form
.spr        Generated Screen Program (previous versions of FoxPro only)
.spx        Compiled Screen Program (previous versions of FoxPro only)
.tbk        Memo backup
.txt        Text
.vct        Visual class library memo
.vcx        Visual class library
.vue        FoxPro 2.x view
.win        Window file
```